# Exception handler catch(...) in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I understand that exception handler catch(...) in C++ handles any type of exception. I am wondering what happens if it has to handle an exception that is of some class type - is the object of that class passed to this handler by reference or by value?

This is the code that could help in understanding this. When the exception of type B is thrown in "Inner try", an unnamed temporary object of class B is created with the default constructor of class B. When I run this program, copy constructor of class B doesn't get called at all, and this unnamed temporary object of class B is destroyed only after executing "Outer try 3", which means that object was propagated backwards all the way to the "Outer try 3". So my guess is that objects are passed by reference to the catch(...) handler, but I wanted to see if this is correct reasoning.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class A {
    public:
        A() {
            cout << "Default constructor of class A" << endl;
        }
        A(const A& a) {
            cout << "Copy constructor of class A" << endl;
        }
        A(A&& a) noexcept {
            cout << "Move constructor of class A" << endl;
        }
        ~A() {
            cout << "Destructor of class A" << endl;
        }
    };
    
    class B {
    public:
        B() {
            cout << "Default constructor of class B" << endl;
        }
        B(const B& b) {
            cout << "Copy constructor of class B" << endl;
        }
        B(B&& b) noexcept {
            cout << "Move constructor of class B" << endl;
        }
        ~B() {
            cout << "Destructor of class B" << endl;
        }
    };
    
    int main() {
        try {
            try {
                try {
                    try {
                        throw A();
                    }
                    catch (A a) {
                        cout << "Inner try" << endl;
                        throw B();
                    }
                }
                catch (...) {
                    cout << "Outer try 1" << endl;
                    throw;
                }
            }
            catch (...) {
                cout << "Outer try 2" << endl;
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (...) {
            cout << "Outer try 3" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm....I don't think it is passed to exception handler at all....`catch(...)` is called when a uncatched exception occurs, but it does not get exception itself. So it does not mean 'how it passed' because it does not pass as far as I know.

Comment: I added code to my question, so if you could check it out that would be great.

Comment: *which means that object was propagated backwards all the way to the "Outer try 3"* It isn't clear what "propagated" means. There is no visible trail of that object. The object was destroyed after the exception was handled, and it was not copied. This is all we know (and need to know).

Comment: After much perusing, I'll admit two things:  (1) I went over § 18 of the standard a few times, and I cannot find any mention of a reference pinning to a catch-all handler. It would certainly make sense it would do so, as it would be the most efficient in advancing the object through the outer handlers until, perhaps, it reached one that required a by-value copy, but I could not find standard language that mandates it. And (2) I want my hour back :-)

Comment: There are plenty of folks on this forum that, I swear, sleep with the language standard under their pillows and whisper sweet nothings to it on a daily basis. I'll bump this up another notch on the hopes one of them will pick it up. I've studied it, and retain a lot of it, but some of these peeps are just machines when it comes to stuff like this. Hopefully one of them can offer something deeper. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you throw an exception, the *exception object* is created from the operand to `throw`. It is an object stored in an unspecified way.

When a matching handler for the exception is reached and the handler is not `...`, then the handler's parameter is initialized from the exception object.

Essentially, if you declare a `catch` parameter as a non-reference type, you are getting a copy of the exception object (or of a base class subobject) in the handler. This is what you see in the `A` handler and why there is a call to the copy constructor. The copy lives until the handler exits. If you declare the parameter a reference type, then you will get a reference to the exception object and it will always refer to the same object if you rethrow the exception.

Rethrowing with `throw;` does not actually do anything with the parameter of the `catch` clause. It simply causes the exception handling to continue searching the `catch` clauses and stack unwinding. The exception object is still the same.

Nothing about this changes if the handler is `catch(...)`. There is no variable (reference or not) to initialize in the handler, but `throw;` will rethrow and continue the search for a handler with the same exception object.

When a handler exits without rethrowing the exception, then the exception object is destroyed. This happens at the end of your outer-most `catch` for the `B` exception object and at the end of the inner-most `catch` for the `A` exception object. (You get two destructor calls to `A`, one for the `catch` parameter and one for the exception object.)